# Issue with opening COM Port

Tags: c++, bluetooth, port, serial-communication

In order to read data from a Bluetooth device(a Disto), the device gets paired with the PC ,by using the pair code, and then the below code is used to open the specific COM port:

```
Port.Format(Str("\\\\.\\COM%d"),m_DistoSerialPort);
CreateFile(Port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

It works without problem in every version of windows and all kind of that device(Disto). Only in windows 8(and 8.1) when it comes to this line a little message pops up at the right corner of the screen saying "Adding a device. Tap to set up your Disto xxxx" and then it fails to connect and the code returns with "E_ACCESSDENIED General access denied error".

Also, again with execution at this method, the "Allow a device to connect"(in Bluetooth icon on taskbar) gets enabled. While in windows 8 clicking on this is no help, in windows 7 it asks for the pair code again and that CreateFile method works fine.

Does it mean that the device isn't paired properly although it was paired? Is it a problem with opening the port or making a connection?

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Even if I remove the GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE access it fails.

Comment: abhishek, In my case, after looking on the Event viewer(try this) it revealed that the Windows(I think the local Bluetooth adapter) wasn't able to write/save the pin code of the Bluetooth device-and that's why it pops out the message every time asking for the code- which in turn was due to the device firmware not being upgraded. I ended up using http://32feet.codeplex.com/ APIs.